# creating a correlation matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a file that has a matrix of 500 rows (binary scores) and 120 columns. The file is a simple matrix of 0s and 1s.

```
>file

00010010101010
01001010100101
00101001010001
11110101001010
```

I am writing a function that uses a special correlation formula to find this correlation between the rows. It takes two vector rows as input fn(row1, row2). eg. row1 and row2 and calculates this special correlation.

Example

```
>fn(file[1,], file[2,])
>0.32
```

I am able to do it for two rows but how can I create a 500x500 correlation matrix for all rows. Can someone please help with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
corr.mat <- outer(seq_len(nrow(file)), seq_len(nrow(file)),
                  Vectorize(function(i, j) fn(file[i,], file[j,])))
```

If this is too slow for your needs, there might be better approaches but you'll have to show what `fn` is supposed to do.

P.S.: `file` being the name of a function in R, you should avoid using it for your own variables.

Comment: thank you, I will try it and see what happens. fn calculates a prespecified tetrachoric correlations. So I wanted to create a 500x500 correlation matrix for all the row variables in the data frame. I will try it and see.